# Wind vectors and direction using cartopy in python getting type error

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr

#-- open netcdf file
ds = xr.open_dataset('uv.nc')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6))

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.coastlines(resolution='50m', linewidth=0.3, color='black')

ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, linewidth=0.5, color='gray', 
             xlocs=range(-180,180,30), ylocs=range(-90,90,30))

ax.set_title('Wind velocity', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')

ax.quiver(ds.longitude[::2], ds.latitude[::2], ds.u10[0,::2,::2], ds.v10[0,::2,::2], 
         transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.savefig('plot_matplotlib_vector_rect.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
```

i just want to plot wind vectors
then I was getting error

```
return matplotlib.axes.Axes.draw(self, renderer=renderer,
TypeError: draw_wrapper() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inframe'
```

can anyone help me

Comment: You haven't included the full stack trace, but one of your packages may be out of sync with Matplotlib. See [here](https://github.com/CLIMADA-project/climada_python/issues/58), for related example.